# Get Non repeating rows from an array column in sequential order pyspark

Tags: azure, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a pyspark dataframe with 2 columns. Column1 is an integer column and Column2 is an ArrayType. I need to get a dataframe without any repeating elements in the preceeding rows of that Column2. In Column2, If an element in a row is repeated in any of the preceeding rows then than entire row should be ignored.

Consider below dataframe, In row 3, 39 is an repeating element so that entire row should be ignored.

[image]

Expected Result dataframe

[image]

I've tried using explode array column then window functions to remove duplicates. But it doesn't give the expected result.

Comment: Yes @DileeprajnarayanThumula

Comment: dilip_df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(Column1=row[0], Column2=row[1]) for row in data], schema=schema)
dilip_windowSpec = Window.orderBy("Column1")
dilip_df = dilip_df.withColumn("lag_Column2", lag("Column2").over(dilip_windowSpec))
def has_intersection(arr1, arr2):
    if arr1 is not None and arr2 is not None:
        return bool(set(arr1) & set(arr2))
    else:
        return False

dilip_intersection_udf = udf(has_intersection, BooleanType())
dilip_df_filtered = dilip_df.filter(~dilip_intersection_udf("Column2", "lag_Column2") | (col("lag_Column2").isNull())).drop("lag_Column2")

Comment: Can you try if this helps

Comment: here we are checking between previous and current row, but we need to check current row with all the previously captured rows

Comment: df_exploded = df.select("Column1", F.explode("Column2").alias("Element"))
window_spec = Window.orderBy("Column1")
df_exploded = df_exploded.withColumn("prev_elements", F.collect_set("Element").over(window_spec.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow - 1)))
df_result = df_exploded.filter(~F.array_contains(F.col("prev_elements"), F.col("Element")))
df_final = (df_result
            .groupBy("Column1")
            .agg(F.collect_list("Element").alias("Column2"))
            .orderBy("Column1"))

Comment: Can you try this.

Comment: this approach also doesn't giving us the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Try to self join this dataframe and list all Column1 values which should be removed. Something like this:

```py
df_exploded = df.select(df.Column1, explode(df.Column2).alias("Column2"))
df_join1 = df_exploded.alias("df1")
df_join2 = df_exploded.alias("df2")
df_to_remove = (
  df_join1
  .join(
    df_join2, 
    [df_join1.Column2 == df_join2.Column2, df_join1.Column1 > df_join2.Column2]
  )
  .select(df1.Column1)
  .dropDuplicates()
)
df_final = df.join(df_to_remove, ["Column1"], "left_anti")
```

I didn't run this code so there may be some issues, but this is idea.

Comment: But it's not giving desired output